# Visual Studio not recognizing members of the Pygame module

Tags: visual-studio

Im currently using pygame to build a really simple game, however visual studio keeps flagging the use of pygame members as problems. IT's very annoying and is confusing when trying to find any real problems. Any ideas on how to fix this or why this is happening would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Could you explain with more detail what those problems are?

Comment: like for example my code contains pygame.K_UP which is included in the pygame framework. I checked the documentation and the code still runs perfectly but for some reason I still get an error in visual studio debugging. I put a discord image link below of the error msg

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/435575746053013524/455487267729833987/unknown.png